# Blazor - Application may no longer respond until reload. Reload

Tags: blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor.
I'm hosting a Blazor Server app on Window 2016 machine(IIS). If I leave the app hanging for a long time on the browser, then it shows this error message 'An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded. Reload'

How can fix this issue? How can I make the app reload if the session times out?

[image]

Comment: How long is a long time?  If you are talking more than 24 hours, it could be related to application pool recycling.  Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66447345/10787774

Comment: Like more than an hour. It usually happens on a mobile phone when i minize the web browser.

Comment: This implies an unhandled exception is occurring.  If you were debugging on a laptop running Chrome for example, you could use Chrome's 'Inspect' function to get more information about the error.  If that is not possible you may want to introduce some logging into your application, and put some try/catch blocks around code you think might be throwing the exception.

Comment: I have attached the error message I got from console tab. Does it ring a bell? I get this error if the browser is inactive for a long time. How can i handle this issue?

Comment: I found this post that sounds like your issue.  Please have a look and see if it can help you.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18740

Comment: any luck.. I have the same issue