# Blazor problem in IIS Windows Server 2012 - "An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded."

Tags: iis, blazor, iis-express, blazor-server-side

I have a problem with the first login to the blazor server side application while the signalR connection is established with the application.

**The application is hosted on IIS Windows server 2012** (production server).

When debugging an application in **IIS Experss Visual Studio I do the same case and the error does not occur**, everything works fine in IIS Express.

Could there be any difference between IIS Windows Server 2012 and IIS Experess in SignalR methods?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to application pool recycling, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443520/how-to-keep-alive-my-blazor-server-side-app-iis-8-5/66447345#66447345

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Websockets for SignalR:
[image]